# How to set buffer size for appsink?

Tags: gstreamer

There is an audio pipeline from `filesrc` to `appsink`. It gives 32ms buffers. How to force it to hand me 10ms audio buffers?

Comment: Is this question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081406/force-gstreamer-appsink-buffers-to-only-hold-10ms-of-data

Comment: @mpr, no, its title is just too general.

Answer (score 2):

Use `audiobuffersplit` in-between `appsink` https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/gst/audiobuffersplit/gstaudiobuffersplit.c

`g_object_set(audiobuffersplit, "output-buffer-duration", 1, 100, NULL);` Will set it to split the buffer by a hundredth of a second(10ms)